# urllib2.urlopen('ur') gives error

Tags: python, urllib2

I am new to python and trying to extract the contents of a page. When I do `urlopen('http://www.google.com')`, I get the following error :

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>    
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1185, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1160, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
```

Any solutions to this ?

Comment: Please indent your error traceback correctly.  Also, please include your actual code.

Comment: The error traceback started as a short, single-spaced, easy-to-read thing.  Why is it double-spaced here?

Answer (score 3):

that error message occurs if your net is offline

Comment: oh yeah something was prong with the proxy configuration .Thanks a lot