# python's urllib2.urlopen() either raises [errno 2] or appears stuck forever

Tags: python, urllib2

I am new to Python, and now I'm learning to write some web-scraping scripts with it. But some strange thing keeps happening and I don't know why. And after testing around a little bit I believe the problem lies in the `urllib2.urlopen()` function. Hear me out:

When I open up Python interpreter in bash using `python` and type in:

```
import urllib2
urllib2.urlopen("http://www.baidu.com/") # which is a Chinese version of Google that most of us use only to test if the network connection is fine
```

things get ugly pretty fast:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory>
```

I don't know what it exactly means but I did run some research on the web. Although most of the result failed to help with my case, I did see some one claiming by using `sudo` everything works fine.

So I gave it a shot, opening python from bash with `sudo python` and then I ran the exact same code as above. This time it appears to be stuck forever. I had to use `KeyboardInterrupt` in the end, and no matter how long I wait while the program's stuck, I get the same traceback result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1181, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1007, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 562, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I am running python on my Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop from a portable flash drive, and currently it's running behind my company's proxy. I don't know if it's the proxy's problem, and I have tried setting environment proxy by

```
$ export http_proxy="http://domain\username:password@proxyserver:port"
```

so that at least `wget` works fine.

As comparison, when I `ssh` to my desktop computer back in my home and run the same code, it all seems alright, with or without `sudo`:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:09:49) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>> urllib2.urlopen("http://www.baidu.com/")
<addinfourl at 3071291372L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0xb71d6eec>>
>>>
```

I have tried running Ubuntu from the same flash drive back home on my laptop, it wasn't that nice either, but I don't remember the details. I will bring it home and test it out after work today for more information and post them back here. Until then, anyone help?

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225746/urllib2-urlopenur-gives-error?rq=1) answer yours?

Comment: It does confirm my doubt about the proxy configuration, but I still don't know how to get my proxy right :/

Comment: add `print(repr(os.environ.get('http_proxy')))`, to check what value python sees. Does proxyserver support http basic authentication?

Comment: python returns exactly what I passed to `http_proxy` in my `export` command (well, not exactly the same. the backslash separating domain and username becomes two backslashes. I don't know if that's supposed to be like this. that aside, everything else is expected); as for the basic authentication, I believe our proxy server supports that, since I use this to configure my proxy for my `apt` package manager as well, and it works fine, so does `wget`

Comment: you could use `nc` as a server to see what headers `wget` compared to `urllib2` sends. Or use a network sniffer such as wireshark, to see the difference.